# AWS Lambda function not respecting batch size 1 when reading from SQS Queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, amazon-sqs

I recently set up a simple AWS Lambda function reading from an SQS FIFO queue. The jobs I am running in Lambda need to be ran concurrently at a specific time. I assumed that batch size 1 would enforce each job to be mapped to a separate Lambda instance when sent in bulk. However, I am seeing consecutive jobs sent to the queue being ran in the same instance and running serially, like a batch job would.

I expected setting batch size = 1 to force concurrent execution of jobs in the SQS queue, but see them running serially in Lambda.

Is there anything I'm missing about the batch size=1 parameter?

Edit:

Here's how I'm sending the jobs:

```py
for req in reqs:
  rand_str = str(random.randint(1, 2**15))
  queue.send_message(
        MessageBody=json.dumps(req),
        MessageDeduplicationId=rand_str,
        MessageGroupId=rand_str
    )
```

and here's the lambda handler:

```py
def handle_request(event, context):
    request = event['Records'][0]
    payload = json.loads(request["body"])
    b = Bot(payload)
    b.run()
    handle_result(b)
```

Comment: Did you set a reserved concurrency for your Lambda function? That may explain this behavior. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html

Comment: I found out that the jobs were finishing too quickly to be run concurrently. When I added a `sleep` to wait until the required run time, they spun up separate instances as intended. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

When we use FIFO queue of SQS, only one batch for one group is available. Use standard queue instead.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-scaling

Comment: The docs you link to say "_Your function can scale in concurrency to the number of active message groups._" OP creates a new message group for each message (see `rand_str`), so there should be more parallelization. Standard queues may or may not be a more appropriate solution - but FIFO is probably not the root cause of the issue here.